# convert "Yes" or "No" to boolean

Tags: powershell, boolean, boolean-expression

I want to parse user values contained in .CSV file. I don't want my users to enter  "Yes" or "No" but instead enter "True" or "False". In each case I want to  convert to the equivalent boolean values: `$true` or `$false`. Ideally I would like a default value, so if there's  misspelt "Yes or "No" I would return my default value: `$true` or `$false`.

Hence, I wondered if there is a neat way of doing this other than

```
if(){} else (){}
```

Comment: I have problems with your 'misspelling' caveat here.  So, you're saying if the user enters 'Yen' that you want it to be $true?  What are the conditions?  The first letter has to match?

Answer (score 6):

One way is a `switch` statement:

```
$bool = switch ($string) {
  'yes' { $true }
  'no'  { $false }
}
```

Add a clause `default` if you want to handle values that are neither "yes" nor "no":

```
$bool = switch ($string) {
  'yes'   { $true }
  'no'    { $false }
  default { 'neither yes nor no' }
}
```

Another option might be a simple comparison:

```
$string -eq 'yes'            # matches just "yes"
```

or

```
$string -match '^y(es)?$'    # matches "y" or "yes"
```

These expressions would evaluate to `$true` if the string is matched, otherwise to `$false`.

Comment: don't forget the `default` clause

Comment: Using `-ieq` and `-imatch` will make them case-insensitive.

Comment: @Eris PowerShell comparison operations are case-insensitive by default. You neet to use `-ceq`/`-cmatch` to make them case-sensitive.

Comment: @Ansgar Thanks so much .  I hate typing so the $string match is one I will test out   - I think i need to learn regex  tho ;-) . Be good if worked with "yes" and "YES"

Comment: Instead of `'^y(es)?$'`, you could also use `-like 'y*'`

Comment: `-like 'y*'` would match any string that starts with a `y`. I thought that might be too broad, so I chose to not list this variant.

Answer (score 5):

Ah, the magic of powershell functions, and invoke expression.

```
function Yes { $true }
function No { $false }

$magicBool = & $answer
```

Note: This is case insensitive, but will not handle misspellings

Comment: It is all fun and games until someone types `rd *`.

Comment: The OP said they were parsing a file, I'm assuming they have control over the input.

Answer (score 1):

If the only possible values are "Yes" and "No" then probably the simplest way is

```
$result = $value -eq 'Yes'
```

With misspelled values and the default `$false` the above will do as well.

With misspelled values and the default `$true` this will work

```
$result = $value -ne 'No'
```

Comment: $result =  $ForcePasswordChange -ne 'No'  seems to be the most elegant solution as I want the default to be $true unless the client explicit requests this.  Loads of good suggestions everyone. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All of these are valid approaches.  If you are looking for a one liner, this will validate it is an acceptable value and set to boolean true if in the 'true' value set.  This will also give you a default $false value.

```
$result = @("true","false","yes","no") -contains $value -and @("true","yes") -contains $value
```

For a default $true value you would need something like so.

```
$result = $true

if (@("true","false","yes","no") -contains $value) {
    $result = @("true","yes") -contains $value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a full snippet of your existing code, something like this would probably be an alternative path to take, as opposed to a string of IF statements.

NOTE: This will not handle simple 'Y' or 'N' input, but **is case insensitive.**  So, you should be able to see 'yes' or 'YES' working, as well.

```
$myVar = Read-Host 'What is your answer?'
switch ($myVar)
{
  Yes {$myVarConverted = $true; break}
  True {$myVarConverted = $true; break}
  No {$myVarConverted = $false; break}
  False {$myVarConverted = $false; break}
  default {"Invalid Input"; break}
}
Write-Host $myVarConverted
```

Please see my additional comment on your question about the 'misspelling' caveat.  That's difficult to code around without specific restrictions or requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I do Yes-No answers:

```
function ask-user
{
   [CmdletBinding()]
   Param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
      [string] $question
   )
   Process
   {  $answer = read-Host $question
      if ("yes" -match $answer) {$true}
      elseif ("no" -match $answer) {$false}
      else {ask-user $question}
   }
}
```

You can easily substitute true and false for yes and no.
This one is case insensitive, and will match valid abbreviations.  (Y or N).
In the case of misspellings, it asks again.  Yeah, I could have done it without recursion, but I'm lazy.

Comment: I see what you are doing, you force a "yes" or "no"  else ask again .  I might upper case it so that is handled as well. Good suggestion.

Comment: It's case insensitive, because that's how -match works.  I've tried it with capital Y or N.

Answer (score 0):

These are great solutions above, but let me just say that this whole topic just proves the vast shortcomings of Powershell...

```
  [System.Convert]::ToBoolean("False") -eq $true ? 
  [System.Convert]::ToBoolean("0") -eq $true ?
```

Really?
Give me a f--kin break.

Answer (score 0):

For me :-

```
Function convert2Bool($this) { return ($("False","0","","N","No",'$False',"Off") -notcontains [string]$this) }
```

can adjust if you don't want $null blank-string going to $false, else fine.